# How in Djnago admin to allow adding only one object in Inline section?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin

I need allow user to add only one object.
How to make it? How to remove button `Add another ...`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might want to check out the following link : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-options

There's a `.max_num` option that limits how many items can be added using the admin form.